# how can i use material-ui offline on machine that does not connect to internet

Tags: material-ui

I want to use `material-ui` on some machine that does not have any connection to the internet.

Only inner network that can show web client pages from some server that does not connected to the internet.

I try to use it by downloading the [material-ui.production.min.js](https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@1.5.1/umd/material-ui.production.min.js)
but this is not work at all

How to do it?

Comment: npm install @material-ui/core ?

Comment: @JleruOHeP: not work ... try already :(

Comment: then can you explain a bit better how do you want to use it and how your page is accessed? Also how do you reference the material-ui in your code?

Comment: @JleruOHeP: i have some private network - that mean that i have server and 20 machine that are connected thru network cable .. no global internet access ...